# mnist dataset. not predicting correctly on real life handwriting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I am trying to predict handwriting from real data instead of test data that has been given in mnist by using keras and tensorflow ,but not able to predict correctly .On test and train data i am getting 96-97 percent accuracy , therefore it is not overfitting .here is my image

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2IYP.png)

and here is my code to read image using open cv and resizing it using numpy ,please help

```
img = cv2.imread('seven.png')
img = cv2.resize(img,(28,28))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = np.invert(img)

img = img/255
img = img.astype('float64')

print(img)

plt.imshow(img)

img= np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
print(img.shape)
```

here is the prediction getting 6 as an answer:-

```
pr = model.predict(img)
print(np.argmax(pr[0]))
```

Comment: This is not a programming problem, its just failure to generalize outside of the training/testing set, your samples are just too different from the MNIST digits.

Comment: ok thank you so much i was thinking the same , also tried on fashion dataset getting same results.

Comment: is this dataset overfitted on mnist dataset itself?, that why its not able to genralize

Comment: Maybe you can use some data augmentation technics to make mnist look more like your data. Or you can look into how transfer learning or domain adaptation deals with these issues.